# Where to post CSS related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have question related to Drupal and to CSS. On [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com) they say CSS is a general thing and not Drupal specific.

So then the question is what is the best place to post CSS related questions based on a Drupal installation?

Comment: Is it a CSS question that has nothing to do with drupal as such (and that it is on a drupal installation is just incidental and could be on any CMS)? Or is it about something that is specific to it being on a drupal installation?

Comment: Depends. Sometimes the solution could be change of css and sometimes solutions is to rebuild templates in drupal...

Answer (score 4):

If the issue is a CSS coding issue, post it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). If the question is strictly related to the templates of Drupal, it may be more on-topic there. If you can narrow it down to a HTML/CSS issue, Stack Overflow is the place.

Make sure to include the corresponding HTML, CSS you have used/tried. If you incorporate that with the Stack Snippet tool, you even have an up-and-ready demo.

Comment: That's a very big thing. Creeting a jsfiddle does mean you understand the problem already which is sometimes not clear at all.

Comment: @Justme Creating a JSFiddle means you have code, whether you understand it or not doesn't matter. You can also use our own in house version: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @James is correct. And you would most likely know the part of the page where it is going wrong, a button, a div. Work from there.

Comment: Thxs for your answers. I somebody has experience in Drupal you would probably not saying that. Besides the fact. I have experience in drupal but some css code is just to far from me. Sometimes it is getting with a module but is conflicting with other modules. So here we are. Having drupal experience, some ccs experience but not enought. Yep, life is a adventure...

Comment: In order to help you we need a narrowed down question. If you are not experienced enough you should either learn (preferred) or let someone else do it.

Comment: Small example: On page http://xenofilia.thedrupalchecklist.com/ there is a responsive image block in the header of the page. If the page is show on a small device the images are resposive but the yellow menu is not going up. If I asked this to a css group without drupal knowlegde then big change they don't understand it all... any suggestion where to post it?

Comment: Maybe try reading a bit first. Stack's Drupal site, Stack Overflow's Drupal tag, and the Drupal documentation and forums. See if someone else is having the same or similar issue. I know time is precious, and learning can be tricky/time consuming, but sometimes there really is no way to avoid having to put an hour or two aside and read someone else's code or the documentation.